# cannot send custom event in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

I'd created a custom event:

```
class SomeEvent extends Event {
    public static var SOMETHING_CHANGED = "somethingChanged";

    public var propery1: String;
    public var property2: String;

    override public function clone():Event {
        var evt: GraphicsEvent = new SomeEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        evt.propery1 = propery1;
        evt.propery2 = propery2;
        return evt;
    }
}
```

after that I added listener to class extending Sprite

```
class SomeClass extends Sprite {
    public function SomeClass() {
        this.addEventListener(SomeEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED, somethingChangedHandler);
    }
    ....
    public somethingChangedHandler(e: SomeEvent) {
        trace("Got event!!");
    }
}
```

and finaly I dispatch an event

```
var e = new SomeEvent(SomeEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED);
e.propery1 = "AAA";
e.propery1 = "BBB";
dispatchEvent(e);
```

after this all I got no trace, hence event is not cauhgt. Here's the question: what is done wrong?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** please note that I'm sending event from class different from `SomeClass`, that class extends `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: The clone function of the first code has GraphicsEvent, i guess thats not the right type?

Comment: The second example contains an event type called GraphicsEvent, but not SomeEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED, is that right?

Comment: Well I missed that. In my code I have `GraphicsEvent` everywhere

Comment: The clone function should return SomeEvent, it now returns Event.

Comment: I cannot find the 'inline' keyword in the documentation, what does it mean? Btw do you have a compile error?

Comment: Well,it's not actionscript but HaXe code. It mean that var is placed everywhere it called during compilation. It's a great feature of HaXe missing in AS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you dispatching from the class named SomeClass?

```
var e = new SomeEvent(SomeEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED);
e.propery1 = "AAA";
e.propery1 = "BBB";
dispatchEvent(e);
```

Has to be inside `SomeClass` for the event handler to get triggered. Or you need to dispatch it using an instance of `SomeClass` as in.

```
var e = new SomeEvent(SomeEvent.SOMETHING_CHANGED);
e.propery1 = "AAA";
e.propery1 = "BBB";
someClassInstance.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: Well, I saw many examples where events (instances of Event) were sent from controller or model (which extends EventDispatcher), and handled by sprites. That looks starange and not convenient that I have to throw event from the same class.

Comment: You dont. Basically you need to listen for event on an instance of a class that can throw that event. In your case you are listening for event dispatched by this, which is SomeClass. You may have seen examples where bubbling mechanic is utilized with DisplayObject objects that are on the display list. For that to work you need to dispatch your event from other objects, but those objects must be displaylist children of the object you are listening on - you need to addChild them first.